# FirebaseAuth listeners not getting called

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I'm not getting any of the callbacks for user creation using `createUserwithEmailAndPassword()`. I'm probably missing something obvious here, but I can't seem to figure out what.

I've enabled the username and password option from the Firebase Console, the user is added to the Firebase users' records, however none of the listeners are firing.

Here's the code where I create the user.

```
firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth)
    {
        // this is not called.
        synchronized (RegisterUser.this) {
            RegisterUser.this.notify();
        }
    }
});
Task<AuthResult> taskResult = firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(model.getEmailId().getValue(),
                model.getPassword().getValue())
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
        {
            //  this never gets called.
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                synchronized (RegisterUser.this) {
                    RegisterUser.this.notify();
                }
            }
            else {
                Logger.e(TAG, "Unable to register user.");
            }
        }
    });
taskResult.isSuccessful(); // returns false makes sense because it's a network call.
synchronized (RegisterUser.this) {
    RegisterUser.this.wait();
}
```

I've tried adding both `OnSuccessListener` and `OnFailureListener` too, but they too are never called.

**Edit :**

So, realized my mistake thanks to @DougStevensen's answer down there. I had multiple threads running, turns out I had a `wait()` statement in one of them, which was blocking the callback even though I had passed the `Executor` thinking the callback would be from the `Executor` provided thread.

Comment: Do you check google play services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are blocking the main thread:

```
synchronized (RegisterUser.this) {
    RegisterUser.this.wait();
}
```

In the hope that the callback will unblock it:

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    synchronized (RegisterUser.this) {
        RegisterUser.this.notify();
    }
}
```

This is not going to work.  First of all, on Android, you should never block the main thread.  That will cause your application to hang and eventually ANR.  Second, the Task asynchronous callbacks all happen on the main thread by default.  So, if you block the main thread, the callbacks will never happen.

Instead of blocking the main thread with java synchronization primitives, you should take up proper Android asynchronous programming practices.  The first thing to do is remove all those `synchronized` blocks so you can see the callback getting invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's the background thread, I don't think Android allows you to wait on the main thread (throws some kind of an exception). Besides I considered that for the background thread too and removed the wait and notify, but still no callback.

Comment: The callbacks are still on the main thread by default.  There are much better ways to manage this than with raw java synchronization primitives. Remove the synchronization and see if that helps.  If it does, then the Firebase SDK is not the problem here, it's the synchronization.

Comment: As I said in my earlier comment I had considered that and removed the code you suggested but I didn't get any callback.

Comment: I know by default all threads are created on the main thread which is why I set the thread to run on the background by specification. And yes I know there are far better/easier ways to get it done than the way I did, but I was just trying something here for fun.

Comment: *"All threads are created on the main thread"* - that statement doesn't make sense.  Even if you start a new thread (which is by definition not the main thread) and run code that attaches callbacks to a Task, those callbacks **will still be on the main thread**, unless you specify an Executor to run them on.  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks

Comment: I suggest simplifying your code down to the bare minimum.  Create a MCVE that illustrates the problem, eliminating all threading.  The callbacks will be invoked in the simplest case, if nothing else, to give you an error.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Aaargh... I had the executor passed to the method call and I removed it just after paste... I will compile an MCVE. As for the statement I agree it was ambiguous, I meant to write any thread that is created on the main thread will be run on the main thread unless specified otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your insistence on the main thread issue, I was infact blocking the main thread, just not the thread the above code ran inside.